# Python logging - exc_info only for file handler

Tags: python, logging

I define root logger and handlers for it:

```
_root = logging.getLogger()
_sh = logging.StreamHandler()
_fh = logging.FileHandler('./error.log', delay = True)
_root.addHandler(_sh)
_root.addHandler(_fh)
```

And module logger instance:

```
_log = logging.getLogger("Main")
# In other file
_log = logging.getLogger("Configuration")
```

Now i call `_log.exception` in try..except block:

```
_log.exception("Test")
```

Now i get traceback in console and file. I try to suppress printing of exc_info with console handler, but not with file handler:

```
class _TraceBackFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        rec.exc_info = None
        return True
_sh = logging.StreamHandler()
_sh.addFilter(_TraceBackFilter())
_root.addHandler(_sh)
```

This works on both file and console handler, traceback is completely removed for all handlers, but i need this only for console. Is any way to suppress exc_info only for console handler, not for file handler?

**EDIT:**

I modify `_TraceBackFilter` class.

```
class _TraceBackFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        if rec.exc_info:
            logging.getLogger(rec.name).log(rec.levelno, rec.getMessage())
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Now its works for console handler, but in file I have doubled messages, one with and one without traceback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `logging.Formatter` subclass for your console handler which returns an empty string from its `formatException` method.

The exception text is cached in the record (in attribute `exc_text`): if this is a false value (e.g. empty string), then `formatException()` will be called to repopulate it, otherwise it won't be. So in your formatter class you may need to override the `format()` method and set `record.exc_text` to a false value before calling the superclass' `format()` method, to ensure your overridden `formatException()` gets called. For example (not tested):

```
class NoExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.exc_text = '' # ensure formatException gets called
        return super(NoExceptionFormatter, self).format(record)

    def formatException(self, record):
        return ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If the _sh handler is being processed first with that filter, it looks like it might be modifying the actual traceback object. Because the same traceback object is passed to both _sh and _fh, _fh receives the already-modified traceback.

You could either make a new traceback object in that filter, sans exc_info, or maybe just swap the order so addHandler is called on _fh first.